# Downloading on Virtual Machines

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, operating-systems, software-activation

Let's say I am using Linux and I have Windows virtual machine. Is it possible to download a Windows only program and run it? If yes, will the data of it stay in the machine after I close the machine?

If no, is there any other ways to run windows application without any issues on Linux?

Many thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: This is exactly what a VM is for. You need to consider it an actual PC with Windows installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Appreciate it.